# How to get label and confidence value from model.executeAsync() tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow.js

I managed to convert my model to model.JSON and manage to load it using `model.executeAsync()`. Then how can i accessed the output to get label and confidence value in order to display it. `model.executeAsync()` just return me a bunch of array value

here is my index.js

```
async function init(){
try {
        model = await 
        tf.loadGraphModel('http://localhost/demo7/model/model.json');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }}

async function predict() {
    console.log("executing model");
    let user_pic = document.querySelector('img');
model.executeAsync(tf.browser.fromPixels(user_pic).cast('int32').expandDims())
console.log('This is your model: ', model, 'This is your prediction: ', prediction) }}
init()
```

result:
[sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czbQ0.jpg)

> [[PromiseResult]]: Array(7)
> 0: e
> dataId: {}
> dtype: "float32"
> id: 3350
> isDisposedInternal: false
> kept: false
> rankType: "3"
> scopeId: 6152
> shape: (3) [1, 300, 4]
> size: 1200
> strides: (2) [1200, 4]
> isDisposed: (...)
> rank: (...)
> **proto**: Object
> 1: e
> dataId: {}
> dtype: "float32"
> id: 3372
> isDisposedInternal: false
> kept: false
> rankType: "1"
> scopeId: 6193
> shape: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czbQ0.jpg)
> size: 1
> strides: []
> isDisposed: (...)
> rank: (...)
> **proto**: Object
> 2: e
> dataId: {}
> dtype: "float32"
> id: 3367
> isDisposedInternal: false
> kept: false
> rankType: "2"
> scopeId: 6182
> shape: (2) [1, 300]
> size: 300
> strides: [300]
> isDisposed: (...)
> rank: (...)
> **proto**: Object
> 3: e
> dataId: {}
> dtype: "float32"
> id: 2254
> isDisposedInternal: false
> kept: false
> rankType: "3"
> scopeId: 3543
> shape: (3) [1, 300, 8]
> size: 2400
> strides: (2) [2400, 8]
> isDisposed: (...)
> rank: (...)
> **proto**: Object

Comment: Could you please add the relevant part of the code that is outputting what you have in the pictures ? By the way it is better to add code than images as people can copy what you have and try it on their own.

Comment: Hi, i already edit the question with sample code. It's my first time asking by the way so not very familiar how to include code etc. sorry

Answer (score 1):

To get your prediction you need

```
const prediction = await model.executeAsync(tf.browser.fromPixels(user_pic).cast('int32').expandDims());
```

Comment: thanks. then how can i accessed the confident value and classes from the output of that code?

Comment: What is the value of `prediction`? Maybe you can edit your question with the output of `console.log(prediction)`